How to dispose my Singleton service in Blazor upon application completion?
I have some service added to Blazor services as Singleton:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDisposableService, DisposableService>(p => new(p.GetService<ILogger<DisposableService>>()!, "Singleton"));
public interface IDisposableService : IDisposable, IAsyncDisposable { }

public class DisposableService : IDisposableService
{
    private static int globalId = 0;
    private int id;
    private readonly ILogger<DisposableService> logger;
    private readonly string type;

    public DisposableService(ILogger<DisposableService> logger, string type)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.type = type;
        id = ++globalId;

        logger.LogInformation("{id}: {type} Service Instance Created", type, id);
    }

    public void Dispose() => logger.LogWarning("{id}: {type} Service Disposed!", type, id);
    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync() => logger.LogWarning("{id}: {type} Service Disposed Asynchronously!", type, id);
}

I expected that upon application completion my service should be disposed, but it is not.
info: BlazorWebApp.DisposableService[0]
      Singleton: 1 Service Instance Created

Different sources say different things, but in fact, I don't see the expected DI behavior in Blazor.
var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDisposableService, DisposableService>();
var host = builder.Build();
host.Run();
public interface IDisposableService : IDisposable { }
public class DisposableService(ILogger<DisposableService> logger)
    : IDisposableService
{
    private readonly ILogger<DisposableService> logger = logger;
    public void Dispose() => logger.LogWarning("Service Disposed!");
}


I'm unable to reproduce the issue. Some details might be missing. Can you turn your question into a Minimal, Reproducible Example?

I would be more focused on the why of this. Are you trying to make a service scoped at a certain request level? If so you should use the scoped service. Normally you should not have to manually dispose of a dependency injected service. Singletons will not live after the application dies.

@MasonA Thanks. In my case, I need a Singleton because a single instance of the service needs to collect some data throughout the application's lifetime and only write it to a file when the application is closed. With Scoped, I would get a bunch of unnecessary service instances in Blazor, even where I don't expect to get them. My mistake, as mentioned in the marked answer, was that I was closing the browser, which interrupted the debugger and the application, so the DI didn't call Dispose when it was needed.

@Steven Here's sample for simple WorkerService:
var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddHostedService();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDisposableService, DisposableService>();
var host = builder.Build();
host.Run();
public interface IDisposableService : IDisposable { }
public class DisposableService(ILogger logger) : IDisposableService
{
private readonly ILogger logger = logger;
public void Dispose() => logger.LogWarning("Service Disposed!");

}

"only write it to a file when the application is closed." This is extremely, because there are many reasons why an application can stop without graceful shutdown, in which case your dispose isn't called and information is not persisted on disk. You might want to reconsider your approach.

Thank you @Steven. In my case, it doesn't matter if the data is actually written or not, what's important is that Dispose is called when the program shuts down normally. Microsoft's documentation says that Dispose should be called and it makes sense, so I'm confused by the actual behavior of the DI container.

How are you exiting the application?

If you're in debug mode then closing the running browser session shuts down the debugging session which doesn't properly exist the running application.  You see no disposals.

If you close the console with <CTL>C then everything closes gracefully and dispose is run.


info: SO78804231.Components.DisposableService[0]
      Singleton: 1 Service Instance Created
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application is shutting down...
Singleton Disposed
warn: SO78804231.Components.DisposableService[0]
      Singleton: 1 Service Disposed Asynchronously!


You're right! I really expected that closing the browser would 'normally' terminate the debugger and the application as a whole. Thank you!

It seems I jumped to conclusions. Even when I terminate the application through C, I see 'Application is shutting down...' but Dispose is still not called. The same issue is not only in Blazor Server but also in a regular WorkerService. How did you manage to reproduce the normal application shutdown on your side?

Are you using the Service somewhere before you exit?  See https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/SO78812322.  You need to navigate to the counter page for DI to create the instance, and thus there to be one to dispose.
